# A confusion of batch variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

I wrote a piece of batch to show .plt files under each sub folder, but get confused with variable "subdir":

```
@echo off
set curdir=%cd%

for /d %%D in (*) do (
    echo %%~fD

    set subdir=%%~fD
    echo %subdir%

    for /r "%subdir%" %%i in (*.plt) do (
        echo %%i
    )

    echo ______DONE______
)

cd %curdir%
```

-- I try to set value of "subdir" as current sub folder, but each time, the printed information shows that it's always equals to the last sub folder:

```
F:\test>show.bat
F:\test\55     //--> this is the name of first sub folder and contains 55.plt
F:\test\Ubuntu // but it prints last folder's name with "subdir"
F:\test\Ubuntu\Ubuntu.plt // and printed file Ubuntu.plt under sub folder Ubuntu
______
F:\test\Nexus 5
F:\test\Ubuntu
F:\test\Ubuntu\Ubuntu.plt
______
F:\test\Ubuntu
F:\test\Ubuntu
F:\test\Ubuntu\Ubuntu.plt
______
F:\test>
```

How can I make "subdir" equals to current sub folder...?

Comment: you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: The line `echo subdir` is supposed to be `echo %subdir%`, right?

Comment: @aschipfl yes, you're right, my typo.

Comment: @npocmaka thanks for sharing~! Tried but seems not work on my pc :(

Comment: You may avoid this error if you eliminate "subdir" variable this way: `echo %%~fD` and  `for /r "%%~fD" %%i in (*.plt) do (`

Answer (score 0):

Your code with using delayed expansion:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "curdir=%cd%"

for /d %%D in (*) do (
    echo %%~fD

    set "subdir=%%~fD"
    echo !subdir!

    for /r "!subdir!" %%i in (*.plt) do (
        echo %%i
    )

    echo ______DONE______
)

cd "%curdir%"
endlocal
```

Comment: As @Aacini pointed out above you do not need to use Delayed Expansion if you just use the command modifiers only.  No point in assigning the FOR variable to an environmental variable.